# Es posible crear una matriz en python (doble lista) en una sola linea

Tags: python

se que no puedo hacer esto:

```
columnas, filas = 5, 4
lista = [[0]*columnas]*filas
```

porque si modifico un elemento de una fila, la modificación se replica. También sé como solucionarlo. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de declararlo en una linea, sin usar ciclos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro!

Prueba esto:

```
columnas, filas = 5, 4
lista = [["0" for y in range(columnas)] for x in range(filas)]

print(lista)
```

Comment: Ojo que estas haciendo una matriz de strings al colocar el 0 entre comillas dobles, siendo que evidentemente el autor pide llenarlo con enteros.

Comment: Ah, pues no lo he entendido... Gracias por avisar Vichoko! Lo malo es que releyéndolo sigo sin pillarlo. ¿Con cualquier entero, aleatorio o en secuencia? Por ejemplo en secuencia, podría ser: 'lista = [[y for y in range(columnas)] for x in range(filas)]'

Comment: La linea de comprensión de listas debería ser: `[[0 for y in range(columnas)] for x in range(filas)]`. Nota que estas llenando la lista de listas de `String` `"0"` en lugar de `Int` `0`.

Comment: ah, vale, es que al ver su código con el [0] (entre corchetes) me tenía despistado con lo que realmente quería hacer. Efectivamente, ese "'0" que he puesto como ejemplo se puede sustituir por casi cualquier cosa. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Kalma. Haciendole unos ajustes a tu resupuesta me quedo con esta que me parece mas compacta: lista = [[0]*columnas for x in range(filas)]

Answer (score 1):

Es común recurrir a la librería [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) de manejo numerico para operaciones matriciales y tensoriales. 
Puedes instalarla con:

```
pip install numpy
```

Con ella lo puedes hacer una matriz de 0s en una linea así:

```
> import numpy
> columnas, filas = 5, 4
> matriz = numpy.zeros((filas, columnas))
> print(matriz)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],           
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```